# BASH -- grep'ing for perl-regex

Tags: regex, bash, perl, grep

Beginner here and I'm trying to understand this. Can someone please break down the part in between the single quotes and describe what it does?

```
grep -oP '(?<=\S\/1\.\d.\s)[345]\d+'
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/YRrnHS/1, there is explanation on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Positive Lookbehind](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) (?<=\S/1.\d.\s) Assert that the Regex below matches
- `\S` matches any non-whitespace character (equal to [^\r\n\t\f\v ])
- `\/` matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
- `1` matches the character 1 literally (case sensitive)
- `\.` matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
- `\d` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
- `.` matches any character (except for line terminators)
- `\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
  Match a single character present in the list below [345]
- `345` matches a single character in the list 345 (case sensitive)
- `\d+` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
- `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Output simply copied from  https://regex101.com/r/HfJSNm/1 : very handy to test/share/have automatic explications on regexes.

Comment: You do not need to copy/paste regex101 output, the post is a dupe and must be closed. [What does this regex mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618), under *Tools: Testers and Explainers*, contains even more tools helping understand a regex pattern.